# mysql-proxy for a remote MySQL server

Tags: mysql-proxy

My program works with a remote MySQL server, and I want to create a local proxy server on my computer in order to make things faster (pool connections, cache queries etc.). I went by the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-proxy.html

I ran, on one console:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql-proxy --proxy-backend-addresses=$MYSQL --log-level=debug2011-11-22 09:43:30: (message) mysql-proxy 0.8.2 started
2011-11-22 09:43:30: (debug) max open file-descriptors = 1024
2011-11-22 09:43:30: (message) proxy listening on port :4040
2011-11-22 09:43:30: (message) added read/write backend: qa-srv:3308
```

And on another console:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql --user root --host=localhost --port=4040
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 81
Server version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10 (Ubuntu)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
```

However, instead of seeing the databases on the remote server (qa-srv) I saw the databases on my local server!

I also tried this:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql --user root --host=qa-srv --port=4040
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'qa-srv' (111)
```

I also tried running the proxy instead of the mysql daemon:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mysql stop
mysql stop/waiting
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql-proxy --proxy-backend-addresses=$MYSQL --log-level=debug --proxy-address=0.0.0.0:3306
2011-11-22 14:14:25: (message) mysql-proxy 0.8.2 started
2011-11-22 14:14:25: (debug) max open file-descriptors = 1024
2011-11-22 14:14:25: (message) proxy listening on port 0.0.0.0:3306
2011-11-22 14:14:25: (message) added read/write backend: qa-srv:3308
```

And on another console:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql --user root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

How can I tell my mysql client to connect to the remote server via the local proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hurray! I found the solution.

On console A:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql-proxy --proxy-backend-addresses=qa-srv:3308 --log-level=debug --proxy-address=127.0.0.1:3306
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (message) mysql-proxy 0.8.2 started
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (debug) max open file-descriptors = 1024
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (message) proxy listening on port 127.0.0.1:3306
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (message) added read/write backend: qa-srv:3308
```

On console B:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u <username-on-remote-database> -h 127.0.0.1
```

Or, alternatively, if you still want your local database active:

On console A:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql-proxy --proxy-backend-addresses=qa-srv:3308 --log-level=debug
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (message) mysql-proxy 0.8.2 started
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (debug) max open file-descriptors = 1024
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (message) proxy listening on port 127.0.0.1:3306
2011-11-22 18:55:02: (message) added read/write backend: qa-srv:3308
```

On console B:

```
erelsgl@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u <username-on-remote-database> -h 127.0.0.1 -P 4040
```